# Como colocar variável concatenada dentro de um <a>?

Tags: php, html, concatenação-de-string

Eu tenho essa linha php:

```
echo '<a href="?p=ultimasnoticias&pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
```

Eu preciso colocar o `.$i.` entre o `<a>.$i.</a>` no meu script html, exemplo:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>.$i.</a>
    </li>
```

Como faço isso?

Comment: O arquivo que contem o html tem a extensão `.html`? Ou é `.php`?

Comment: @AndreiCoelho A extensão de todos os arquivos são `.php`. Mas eu já consegui resolver, obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fácil.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <?php echo '<a href="?p=ultimasnoticias&pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>'; ?>
    </li>
```

Outra opção seria:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="?p=ultimasnoticias&pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a>
    </li>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Para diminuir o código também pode ser:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<li>
   <a href="?p=ultimasnoticias&pagina=<?=$i?>"><?=$i?> 
   </a>
</li>
```